# fsockopen unlimited timeout

Tags: php, timeout, fsockopen

there is a way to make a fsockopen with unlimited timeout ? Like CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$timeout` parameter.

It's right there in the manual: http://php.net/fsockopen

Comment: and prepend set_time_limit(0) to my php file ?

Comment: set_time_limit() is used for PHP execution timeout and has nothing to do with fsockopen. It's 10 years now that I read about people not understanding what is set_time_out for.